# Settings schema 'com.canonical.Unity2d.Panel' is not installed

Tags: 11.10, unity-2d

I'm unable to run unity-2d-panel.   I've tried apt-get --reinstall.
This is with 11.10 32 bit Oneiric - upgraded from Natty.  Any idea how to get past this?
Here is the .xsession-errors when starting Ubuntu 2d: http://paste.ubuntu.com/708039/
In a terminal, I get:

> unity-2d-panel: [FATAL] Settings schema 'com.canonical.Unity2d.Panel' is not installed

Ok.  I've gotten past this, I used dpkg to list all packages having 'unity' in them and re-installed all of them, it turns out some of the dependencies were wrong and somehow unity-2d-places and unity-2d-spread were not installed.  It seems something deeper has gone wrong in my packaging... I'm now having missing icons, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: More context might help -- what version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: What happens when you try to run "unity-2d-panel" in a terminal? (Add the results to your question)

Answer (score 2):

OP has solved the problem themselves and updated the question to reflect this

> Ok. I've gotten past this, I used dpkg to list all packages having
>   'unity' in them and re-installed all of them, it turns out some of the
>   dependencies were wrong and somehow unity-2d-places and
>   unity-2d-spread were not installed.